# Moles "conflict" when using Moles with MsTest

Tags: moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I have found an explicable (but frustrating) behavior when working with Moles and MsTest.

Just imagine the following case:

- "Test DLL A" is using Moles on mscorlib
- "Test DLL B" is using Moles on mscorlib

To improve compilation time, in both cases we are editing the .moles files in order to ask the generation of moles for a single class.

When we do so, our projects will compile perfectly fine.

But when we run the test of our solution the MsTest process will be :

- Copy all DLLs in the "Out" folder
- Run the tests in the "Out" folder

As a consquence, the copy to the "Out" folder will try to copy two version of mscorlib.Moles.dll (one with type 1, and one with type 2) and of course, the second one will overwrite the first one.

And so my test of "Test DLL A" will fail because my mole assembly is not correct.

There are of course two  simple workaround :

- either include all needed types (in all projects) in every .moles file
- either do not use type filtering

Have you ever faced this "problem" also ? is there any other solution ?

Many thanks !

Pierre-Emmanuel
DotNetHub user group lead

Answer (score 1):

This is a late reply I know, but we did run into the same thing here at my shop.

What we ended up doing was creating a project just for moles.  And then having all other unit test projects reference the .dlls created in our MolesProject/Moles folder.

We were able to leverage that and improve build times